# Forwarding references and template templates

Tags: c++, c++11, template-templates, template-function, forwarding-reference

Consider these two template functions:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& bar) {
    // do stuff with bar, which may or may not be an instance of a templated class
}

template<typename U, template<typename> class T>
void foo(T<U>&& bar) {
    // do stuff with bar, which must be an instance of a templated class
}
```

Why does the former accept lvalues (by using a forwarding reference) while the latter does not?

---

It looks like [Can an identity alias template be a forwarding reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851098/can-an-identity-alias-template-be-a-forwarding-reference) may be related to this as well, but it seems to cover a different facet of the restrictions on forwarding references.

Comment: [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/651f0f3ae9afbf39) an alternative solution

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Oh, that's a nice way of doing it too. Could you post your solution as an alternative answer rather than just linking it? There's nothing wrong with adding additional solutions even if a good one already exists if the additional solutions are good as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how the standard says the language should work.

> [14.8.2.1][temp.deduct.call]
>   3.If P is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of P’s type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a
>   reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction. A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue
>   reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter. If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an
>   lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

Only an rvalue-reference to a CV-unqualified template parameter can be deduced as an l-value reference in this manner.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you might be able to use a trait to extract the template template parameter.

```
#include <type_traits>

/***
 * Extract template from template type.
 */
template <typename I> struct get_template;

template <template<class> typename T, typename C>
struct get_template<T<C>> {
  template <typename U>
  using temp = T<U>;
};





template <typename T> struct A{};

struct B;

template<typename W>
void foo(W && bar) {
  typedef typename get_template<typename std::remove_reference<W>::type>::template temp<int> new_type;
  new_type my_variable;
}

int main() {
  A<B> temp;
  foo(temp);
}
```

Or, just overload the function for const & and && as usual.

Comment: Traits are pretty cool, I haven't used them that much but they've been quite useful when I needed them. Ultimately, in what I was working on I was able to use another type parameter that could be passed as `const&` to supply the template template parameter so was able to specify the `&&` argument type as a plain parameter (kind of like Piotr's solution, actually) and asked the question more out of curiosity than needing a specific solution, but this would be useful for situations where that's not doable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retain a forwarding reference parameter, and, at the same time, deduce the type of an argument, you can use the below solution:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct tag {};

template <typename T, typename U, template <typename> class C>
void foo(T&& t, tag<C<U>>)
{

}

template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t)
    -> decltype(foo(std::forward<T>(t), tag<typename std::decay<T>::type>{}))
{
    return foo(std::forward<T>(t), tag<typename std::decay<T>::type>{});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/651f0f3ae9afbf39)